# Doubt about the proof of Moser Iteration in Gilbarg & Trudinger's book

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I was reading Theorem 8.15 about Moser Iteration in Gilbarg and Trudinger's monograph. I understand all the steps of the given proof, but I have the following doubts which could not be cleared by a careful reading.

1. The Authors, as hypotheses for the theorem, require that $f^i\in L^q(\Omega)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $g\in L^{q/2}(\Omega)$ for some $q>n$  but it seems they haven't used these facts anywhere in the proof: is this so and, if not, in which steps are these facts used?
2. Does the theorem fail for $q\le n$?

Please help me to fully understand this proof.

Here I have uploaded a snapshot of the theorem.[image]

[image]

Equation 8.3

\begin{equation}
    Lu=D_i(a^{ij}(x)D_ju+b^i(x)u)+c^i(x)D_iu+d(x)u
\end{equation}.

Equation 8.30

\begin{equation}
     \int_{\Omega}\left(D_ivA^i-vB\right)dx=(\le,\ge)0
 \end{equation}

Equation 8.32

\begin{equation}
    \bar z=|z|+k,\qquad \bar b=\lambda^{-2}(|b|^2+|c|^2+k^{-2}|f|^2)+\lambda^{-1}(|d|+k^{-1}|g|)
\end{equation}

Equation 8.33

\begin{align}
p_iA^i(x,z,p)  & \ge \frac{\lambda}{2}(|p|^2-2\bar b\bar z^2)  \\
      | \bar zB(x,z,p)  |     &\le \frac{\lambda}{2}\left( \epsilon|p|^2+\frac{\bar b}{\epsilon}\bar z^2\right) 
\end{align}

Any Help Hint will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The proof references many inequalities (or other stuff, such as (8.32) ) which are not included in the question. Do some of them depend on $f^i$, $g$?

Comment: Maybe before (8.36): choosing $k$ as in the statement of the theorem. What is $\bar{b}$?

Comment: @supinf  I have edited question , Please Help me.

Comment: @user90189 I have edited question , Please Help me.

Comment: Note that we need $f\in L^q$ and $g\in L^{q/2}$ for the definition of $k$. Otherwise, $k$ would not be finite. Note that this $k$ is carefully chosen and allows us to deduce (8.36) from the previous inequality. Indeed, with this $k$, $\overline{b}$ is bounded by $C = C(\nu)$.

Answer (score 1):

it definitely needs the condition $f^i\in L^q(\Omega)$ and $g\in L^{q/2}(\Omega)$.

1. During the proof, one needs to choose $\chi=\hat{n}(q-2) / q(\hat{n}-2)>1$ (above equation (8.37)). This is possible if and only if $q>\hat n$.
2. The theorem in general fails for $q\leq n$. One can get some clue from the $W^{2,p}$ estimates of elliptic equations. Conside a special case, $f=0$ and $Lu=g$ with $u=0$ on the boundary. The $W^{2,p}$ roughly says $$||u||_{W^{2,q/2}}\leq C||g||_{L^{q/2}}$$
   Recall the Sobolev embedding theorem, $W^{2,q/2}\in L^\infty$ if $q>n$, while this is not true when $q\leq n$.

For a counterexample, one can just take one element  $g\in W^{2,n/2}$ but not in $g\not\in L^\infty(\Omega)$.  Then
$$\Delta u=\Delta g$$
has a solution $u$ while (8.34) can not be true.